# Google App Engine API Explorer HTTPS error when launching from localhost

Tags: google-app-engine, http, https

In a Google App Engine project, I was trying to test my API locally. I  typed `localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer` into the browser, and got the following error from the redirected page (`https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F_ah%2Fapi#p/`).

> You are exploring an API that is described or served via HTTP instead
>   of HTTPS. This is insecure and may be blocked by your browser. To fix
>   this, set up a TLS proxy for your API. Alternatively, you can tell
>   your browser to allow active content via HTTP at this site (on Chrome,
>   click the shield in the URL bar), but this will not improve security
>   or dismiss this message.

If I deploy my app to the cloud, and use `https://my-application-id.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer`, I was able to access the explorer with no problem.

I believe the problem is `localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer` is accessed with `HTTP` instead of `HTTPS`, but I do not know how to fix it. If I try to access `https://localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer`, I got an `SSL connection error`.